# struct declared in tools.h and defined in tools.c. Can't link them to main.c

Tags: c, gcc, struct, static-linking

file **tools.h**:

```
//some macro definitions

struct name;

//other function prototypes
```

---

file **tools.c**:

```
#include "tools.h"

struct name
{
    FILE *src;
    int value;
}


//definitions of functions declared in tools.h
```

---

file **main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tools.h"

int main()
{
    struct name *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct name));
    ptr->FILE = fopen(filename, "r");
    ptr->value = 12;
    ...
}
```

---

1. At first, I built tools.o by using:
   `$ gcc tools.c -c`
   Without any error or warning, `tools.o` was built in the current directory.
2. Now, I tried to build executable by using:
   `$ gcc main.c tools.o -o exe`
   and I got errors of same type (all the errors were of same type, caused due to accessing the struct element). Here's the sample of that error I got:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:17:22: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct name’
   17 |   buffer = malloc(ptr->value+1);
```

---

Please explain why this happened and what wrong I did while linking or in my code.

Comment: Move the full definition of `struct name` to `tools.h`. It cannot be an opaque struct if you need to know its members or its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tools.h file

```
#ifndef TOOLS_H
#define TOOLS_H

#include <stdio.h>

struct name
{
    FILE *src;
    int value;
};

int foo(struct name*);
struct name *bar(double, FILE*, const char *);  //prototypes of functions defined in tools.c
#endif
```

tools.c

```
#include "tools.h"

int foo(struct name*)
{
   /* ... */
}

struct name *bar(double, FILE*, const char *)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some confusion with regards to forward declaration of a structure and a structure declaration (which defines a type).

From [Forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

> *a forward declaration is a declaration of an identifier (denoting an entity such as a type, a variable, a constant, or a function) for which the programmer has not yet given a complete definition.*

In `tools.h`, this

```
struct name;
```

is forward declaration of structure `struct name`. Note that, it declares an incomplete type because the specification *[list defining the content]* of `struct name` is unknown at this time.

You have included the `tools.h` in `main.c` and when compiling `main.c` compiler does not find the specification of `struct name` and hence, throwing error on the statements using it.

In `tools.c`, you are declaring the `struct name` (which defines a type):

```
struct name
{
    FILE *src;
    int value;
};
```

when compiling `tools.c`, compiler knows about the specification of structure `struct name` and hence, it's compilation is successful.

The other post [by @0___________] gives the appropriate way to solve this problem.

Comment: while compiling main.c, I also included tools.o (library created from tools.h and tools.c): `gcc main.c tools.o -o exe`. Doesn't the linker find the definition of `struct name` in tools.o and link to it? Or is my understanding of 'linking' by linker is wrong? Or does changing the order works?   , like this: `gcc tools.o main.c -o exe`? (I could have tried this myself, but right now I arleady changed the code as solutions told here, so I don't have those same file).

Comment: .... This page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linker/ says that linker links **object** modules. So I think in my case, when I give this command: `gcc main.c tools.o -o exe`, the gcc compiler first attempts to compile `main.c` to produce `main.o` and plans to link both main.o and tools.o. But since `main.c` is compiled **first**, without any proper definition of `struct name` in availability, the compiler threw that error. I'm I right?

Comment: @Cinverse Yes, you are right.